# Error Login In My HMVC Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-hmvc

i have a problem with my login in application . in my login authentication a create a library name is "auth" and i also was call "auth" in autoload but when i call a function in "auth" the error say

```
Message: Undefined property: Auth::$session
```

here is my library "auth"

```
class Auth {
    public function cek_auth()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->sesi  = $this->ci->session->userdata('isLogin');
        $this->hak = $this->ci->session->userdata('stat');
        if($this->sesi != TRUE){
            $this->session->set_flashdata("pesan", "Sesi Login anda telah habis");
            redirect('user/login');
            exit();
        }

    }
    public function hak_akses($kecuali="")
    {
        if($this->hak==$kecuali){
            echo "<script>alert('Anda tidak berhak mengakses halaman ini!');</script>";
            redirect('dashboard');
        }elseif ($this->hak=="") {
            echo "<script>alert('Silahkan Login!');</script>";
            redirect('c_login','refresh');
        }else{

        }
    }
}
```

my controller :
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller{

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->auth->cek_auth(); //ngambil auth dari library
}
function index()
{
    $hak_akses = $this->session->userdata('lvl');
    if($hak_akses==1) {

        $data['content'] = 'dashboard';
        return $this->load->view('theme/index', $data);
    }

}
```

}

and my autoload :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','session','auth','parser');
```

please give me a best solution , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are using session in your code then make sure to autoload in config.php file by setting an encryption key.** If you don't autoload it then you can load it using `$this->load->library('session')`. **But you must set encryption key in order to autoload or load session in controller functions.**

Reference : [Undefined property: CI::$session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978239/undefined-property-cisession).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the session library inside

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->ci->load->library('session');
    $this->sesi  = $this->ci->session->userdata('isLogin');
}
```